# How to Decode an image and keep the original in Go?

Tags: go, pointers

I have the following bit of code:

```golang
imageFile, _ := os.Open("image.png") // returns *os.File, error

decodedImage, _, _ := image.Decode(imageFile) // returns image.Image, string, error
// imageFile has been modified!
```

When I try to work with `imageFile` after calling `image.Decode` it no longer behaves the same, leading me to believe `image.Decode` modified `imageFile` in some way.

Why is `image.Decode` modifying the original value while at the same time returning a new value for `decodedImage` - isn't this misleading?

How do I retain the original value? Is there a way to make a "real" copy of the file, pointing to a new part of allocated memory?

I just started out with Go, so apologies if I am missing something obvious here.

Comment: What do you mean it has been modified? The original value is the file itself, so if you want to copy the file, then copy the file without decoding it.

Comment: I am calling another function with `imageFile` right after. If I called `image.Decode` before it no longer recognizes the file. If I call it after everything works fine.

Comment: Open it again or seek to the beginning. This isn't related to Go, it's how files work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file on disk is not modified by the code in the question.

The current position of `imageFile` is somewhere past the beginning of the file after the image is decoded.  To read the fie again, [Seek](https://pkg.go.dev/os#File.Seek) back the beginning of the file:

```
 imageFile, err := os.Open("image.png")
 if err != nil { log.Fatal(err) }
 decodedImage, _, err := image.Decode(imageFile)
 if err != nil { log.Fatal(err) }

// Rewind back to the start of the file.
_, err := imageFile.Seek(0, io.SeekStart)
if err != nil { log.Fatal(err) }
// Do something with imageFile here.
```

Replace the `log.Fatal` error handling with whatever is appropriate for your application.